# How to change float('inf') representation?

Tags: python, oop

I want to change float('inf') representation -> ∞, can u help me with it? I try to use this, but it didn't work

```py
class Inf(float('inf')):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return '∞'

inf=Inf()
```

those, when I use print() I want to see '∞' instead 'inf'

I want result like in

```
from sympy import oo
```

but get it with oop

Comment: In what context exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop the `('inf')` in class inheritance. You inherit from classes, not their instances. Then in `__repr__` check if your float is infinity.

```
class FloatWithGlyphInf(float):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if self == float('inf'):
            return '∞'
        else:
            return super().__repr__()

print(FloatWithGlyphInf('inf')) # ∞
print(FloatWithGlyphInf('0'))   # 0.0
```